# Change all values in column

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to change all "-1" values to "4", what should I type in "mysql console" to do this? Please (this is a very noob question)

[pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w4UT9.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following SQL Update statement.

```
update sb_admins_servers_groups
Set srv_group_id=4
Where srv_group_id=-1
```

Let me know if any question!